# To make the water to heat using current

Tags: ac

I want to use nichrome wire as resistor to heat water of 1.5 litres approx if I connect it to 230v ,50hz or else I use a DC current which is easy and better .what happens if any thing wrong with ac current

Comment: Are you talking about literally connecting the nichrome wire straight into the outlet?

Comment: There are very cheap heating elements designed to do exactly this task. They are safe to use, too. If you are making your own regardless, you need to say so, and why, and show you are capable of doing so safely.

Comment: I want a metal which is nontoxic and corrosive resistant and have high resistance cheap also ...can you please suggest me which metal or alloy can I use?? And can I use ac 230v,50hz directly or I use step down transformer  or DC current..

Comment: Mr.harry not exactly but the part that immresed in water is nichrome remaining is copper wire directly to mains ??is it possible

Comment: And what would insulate the water from the wire? The water would short-circuit the wire and the water and pipework would be live. This could kill someone.

Comment: Hey OP, welcome to eesx! As you might have realized from the comments, your question is not as clear as it could be. When somebody asks for clarification in the comment section, please don't forget to add more insights to the question as well!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want it to be corrosive resistant, you cannot use Nichrome.

Nichrome wire is specifically meant to be heated red, and that's what existing immersion heaters do. If you don't heat them red, you don't get the protecting layer of chrome oxide which makes Nichrome so special as a heating material. You cannot heat something red in water.

About corrosives, you have to take care which alloy to use. Many chrome alloys are susceptible to intercrystal corrosion from chloride ions and acids. That's the reason why existing immersion heaters have the Nichrome wire inside a tube of a different chrome-steel alloy. Silica-glass coated heaters offer corrosive resistance against all agents but hot hydrofluoric and phosphoric acid.

Answer (score 4):

Your question sounds worrisome. You are going to sink a plain metallic resistor into the water and connect it to the electricity. The electricity will be on your hands, too.

Proper water heating elements ARE complex. They have watertight outer shell and internal electric insulation which prevent any contact between the electrified part and the water, but still allow the heat to flow.

In addition: Overheating must be prevented. It's far too easy to burn the house without automatic shutdown.

Your task needs more than average good hobbyist level knowledge and practical electrician skills. You seem to have nothing. STOP AS LONG AS NOBODY HAS DIED!

Comment: Yaa I'm very weak in this but I just want to water to heat for small purposes for example boiling eggs ...what can you do if you are in my place please help me sir

Comment: @Praneeth I would buy a ready to use water heater. Today they are available with proper temperature control. Making one at home is too dangerous even for me, who know the requirements and threats. Watertightness is the most difficult thing.

Comment: @Praneeth Then I would buy an egg boiler.

Comment: Is it available ?? How much costs it

Comment: I use glass as container as it is a insulator can  I ?

Comment: @Praneeth Glass between your resistor and water is ok if it's thin enough and filled with some insulating heat transfer compound. Making it safe and working is beyond all ordinary hobbyists skill level.  Glass around the water and a plain resistor is useless, if you must reach the water to boil something. In addition your water probably is ordinary pipe water, not distilled so it will cause also a short circuit. As told: search for egg cooker, electric kettle and immersion cooker.

Comment: You can also buy heating elements sold as spares for various appliances; if you want to build your own appliance, design it around one of these elements.

Comment: Ok short circuit happens ...but now I want to boil eggs in that water which insulator can I use ...please help this is my first appliance I'm preparing

Comment: @Praneeth sorry! How could I sleep any more if someone writes with your still open PC "@User287001, you have killed my child! Burn in the fire of Hell!"

Comment: Hmm ok I understand ...

Comment: @Praneeth You appear to be suicidal, or you value your life less than normal. You are not immortal. I recommend you to go see a doctor.

Comment: No I'm stopping it . I've no clarity so.i ask you questions  on this .please forgive me .thanks for your suggestions